# Create a matrix from variables using subsequent values

Tags: loops, variables, matrix, stata

I have data in Stata with 3 variables, a string `id` and numeric variables (GPS data - latitude and longitude). I would like to convert the variables into a matrix in the following way (the lower table) to calculate the distance between two id-spots for all combinations. So a newly created subsequent column (e.g, `id_1`) has a subsequent(i+1) value of the original variable (e.g., `id`), and so on. However, the following command works only until the n-th row is reached to get a value;  then the subsequent new rows become empty. Thus, the half bottom of the matrix gets missing (the upper table: ///) . For 2000 observations:

```
foreach num of numlist 1/2000 {
   foreach var of varlist id num1 num2   {
        gen `var'_`num'=`var'[_n+`num']
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your specific aim is to create 6000 new variables each with 2000 observations to later calculate (2000 x 1999) / 2 = 1999000 distances. If the latter is the goal, consider e.g. `geonear` from SSC. If you want travel distances,  there are several existing community-contributed commands, e..g `search distance`.

Comment: Suppose you have 2000 observations. Then any reference to `whatever[2001]` or to values in later observations is legal but just returns missing as there is no such observation.

Comment: Thank you Nick. I deleted the post without realising your reply as I figured it myself that I can use "expand 2" to duplicate the whole data set and run the command, then delete the unneeded ones afterards. In this way I could have the whole matrix data. I needed the whole matrix rather than half diagonal. Yes I used geodist which works a wonder. Thank you again for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post an answer if anybody finds any use.

```
//duplicate all observation to create all filled matrix

expand 2, gen(dupindex) 

forvalue i = 1/1999 {
    foreach var of varlist id num1 num2 {
    gen `var'`i'=`var'[_n+`i']
        }
}

//delete the unnecessary columns & rows

forvalue i = 2000/3999 {
    drop id`i' num1`i' num2`i'  
}
drop in 2001/3999
drop dupindex
```

Comment: Nice that you've found a solution. Please mark it as solved.